# C# Protobuf Disable Null Checks

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c#

I have a proto file with this:

```
message Group {
    string name = 1;
    string id = 2;
}
```

and the generate code (using `Grpc.Tools`) gives me code like this for setting name/id:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("protoc", null)]
public string Name {
  get { return name_; }
  set {
    name_ = pb::ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(value, "value");
  }
}
```

The thing is, `name` can be null.  If don't set it, I can serialize/deserialize the message fine, but if I try to do `group.name=null` (usually, I just set it from a db value which may be null) I get an `ArgumentNullException` - is there a way for the generated code to all nulls?  again, nulls are fine, and I can serialize and deserialize the message fine when I just don't set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Protobuf there is no notion of null. Value could be absent in serialized message, then it becomes default in the object. From [proto3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default):

> **Default Values**
>
> When a message is parsed, if the encoded message does
> not contain a particular singular element, the corresponding field in
> the parsed object is set to the default value for that field. These
> defaults are type-specific:
>
> For strings, the default value is the empty string.
>
> ...
>
> Note that for scalar message fields, once a message is parsed there's
> no way of telling whether a field was explicitly set to the default
> value (for example whether a boolean was set to false) or just not set
> at all: you should bear this in mind when defining your message types. ... Also note that if a scalar message field is set to its
> default, the value will not be serialized on the wire.

So you can assign empty string (default value for strings) to the property.

Also there is [`optional`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules) keyword for the field,

```
message Group {
    optional string name = 1;
```

which adds `Clear-` method to object, and translates to C# code like:

```
private string name_;
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("protoc", null)]
public string Name {
  get { return name_ ?? ""; }
  set {
    name_ = pb::ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(value, "value");
  }
}

[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("protoc", null)]
public bool HasName {
  get { return name_ != null; }
}

[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("protoc", null)]
public void ClearName() {
  name_ = null;
}
```

But calling `.ClearName()` has the same effect on serialized message as assigning it to the default empty string, `Name = ""`. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules) too states that presence/absence of `optional` more or less the same:

> `optional`: the same as `singular`, except that you can check to see
> if the value was explicitly set.